# Partition and cloning of Windows XP Image

Tags: partitioning, images, clone

I have to partition and install the same software and OS (win xp) on 10 same devices. What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Should you be wasting your time with XP still? It is no longer supported by Microsoft for updates (apart from security patches)... Obviously if you MUST then who are we to stop you... you could use a disk imaging solution like CloneZilla - it can save your "pre-fabricated computer" as a snapshot (including all your partitions) and can be used to deploy it using multi-cast to your 10 computers simultaneously... don't forget, however, if you are putting the machines onto a Windows domain then you will need to sysprep the machine to remove any SIDs.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately the corporation has software which runs only on winxp.

Comment: You have two solutions for old compatibility: Windows XP Mode (a complete virtual Windows XP that runs inside Windows 7) OR (preferred) is to use Windows 7 compatibility mode for applications. Have you tried this? I seriously think you should rethink using XP as your main operating systems on computers...